# Use StoreEntryId as unique id

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is it a good idea to use `StoreEntryId` as a unique id of exchange items. I've got the problem, like a lot of other developers, that the `ItemId` changes when moving objects in the exchange server. So maybe using `StoreEntryId` is a good idea.

Has anyone any experience with it?

Comment: Nop, the `StoreEntryId` will be changed as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I will try ExtendedProperties.